# Scala : Type Nothing with User defined classes

Tags: scala

In scala `Nothing` is a subtype of every other type.

```
scala> class A {}
defined class A

scala> def x[T >: Nothing](t: T): Unit = {}
x: [T](t: T)Unit

scala> x(new A)
```

When we create an arbitrary class, it automatically becomes a supertype of `Nothing`

1. How this property is maintained in scala? Does the compiler makes `Nothing` extend every other class at compile time?
2. Like this way, is it possible to define a custom class `X` as a subtype of a set of classes(say set **s**) without making `X` extend from all the classes in the **s**? (e.g: Class `X` is a subtype of all the classes in package `com.myproject.models`)

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/195793/how-is-nothing-a-subtype-of-every-other-type-in-scala

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How this property is maintained in scala? Does the compiler makes Nothing extend every other class at compile time?

`Nothing` is not implemented with an actual class, it's a pure artifact of the compiler. The actual handling of the `Nothing` type can be vulgarized as hardcoding `Nothing` in several places inside the compiler, for instance, `isSubType(t1: Type, t2: Type): Boolean` is unconditionally true when `t1 == Nothing`.

> Like this way, is it possible to define a custom class X as a subtype of a set of classes(say set s) without making X extend from all the classes in the s?

No.